# Busco solucionar este error en una vista de pug de un proyecto

Tags: javascript, nodejs

[image: este es el error: Cannot read property 'nombre' of undefined]

Este el codigo de la vista pug: al intentar crear un usuario arroja el error, estoy siguiendo paso a paso el curso backend

```
  form(action='/usuarios/create' method='post')
    .form-group
        label(for='nombre') Nombre: 
        input#nombre.form-control(type='text' name='nombre' value= usuario.nombre class=errors.nombre ? 'is-invalid' : '')
        if errors.nombre
            small#nombreHelp.text-danger
               = errors.nombre.message  
    .form-group
        label(for='email') Email: 
        input#email.form-control(type='text' name='email' value= usuario.email class= errors.email ? 'is-invalid' : '')
        if errors.email
            small#emailHelp.text-danger
               = errors.email.message
```

Este es el codigo de controllers: El error ya no se muestra al hacer el get de la vista pug sino en el post al llenar los datos y enviar la informacion a la vista de la lista de usuarios

```
       res.render('usuarios/create', {errors:{}, usuario: new Usuario()});
    },
    create: function(req, res, next) {
        if (req.body.password != req.body.confirm_password) {
            res.render('usuarios/create', {errors: {confirm_password: {message: 'No coincide con el password ingresado'}}, usuario: new Usuario({nombre: req.body.nombre, email: req.body.email})}) ;
            return;
        }

        Usuario.create({ nombre: req.body.nombre, email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password }, function (err, nuevoUsuario) {
            if (err) {
                res.render('usuarios/create', {errors: err.errors, usuario: new Usuario({nombre: req.body.nombre, email: req.body.email})}) ;

            }else{
                nuevoUsuario.enviar_email_bienvenida();
                res.redirect('/usuarios');
            }
          });
    },
```

Comment: Verifica que las variable `usuario` y `errors` estén bien definidas. El error dice que `usuario` o `errors` es `undefined`. ¿Cómo envías las variables a la vista? Imagino que haces algo como `res.render('vista');`, pero tal vez te haga falta hacerlo así: `res.render('vista', {usuario: usuario, errors: errors});`. ¿Podrías agregar más detalles? Saludos

Comment: tienes toda la razon, Yo tenia mal el codigo, ya lo arregle y funciona, muchas gracias    `create_get: function(req, res, next){res.render('usuarios/create', {errors:{}, usuario: new Usuario()}); },`

Comment: Cuando sale el mismo error despues de enviar la informacion, es un problema de alguna ruta? o sigue siendo del controllers?

Comment: Agrega todo eso en la pregunta. Puedes hacer clic en [edit]. Saludos